# Is 'dicing' a verb in dice games?

Tags: slang

When you're playing Yahtzee or any other dice game, is it correct to use the verb "dicing" when you want to notify whoever is listening? Or is "dicing" a slang word ? Or is it neither? Could it be my not-native-English-speaking fantasy that I may just imagine whatever seems like a possibility?

Anyway, it seems like the English-speaking people I played with did understand it, so it might be a real word, or just as likely it could be that I like to play with words.  Maybe I should keep that to words in Swedish, my native language.

Comment: As a verb, "dicing" means "cut up into small cubes" (like dice!). It's used primarily in a cooking context. The action you're describing, in a gaming or gambling context, is described  in English as "throwing dice".

Comment: “When notify whoever listening” — I don't understand what you mean by this? Also, _att tärninga_ gets exactly one hit in Google, so I wouldn't really leave this one in Swedish either…

Comment: @DanBron - Also, "dicing" is the term used by semiconductor manufacturers for the process of sawing a large semiconductor wafer into individual semiconductor "chips".

Comment: This is one of those many situations where a usage isn't wrong, but neither is it idiomatic in all settings. 'Dicing' _can_ mean 'playing dice' (and is common in the expression 'dicing with death'), but I'd certainly use 'playing dice' instead.

Comment: image = imagine ..sorry,  my bad 

Comment: @Jalto If you look at the bottom of your post, you'll see there is an "edit" button, which will allow you to fix your mistake :-)

Comment: @JaltoV.Inge: what do you want 'dicing' to mean? Is that what you're doing when you play the entire game -  "when can we start dicing?" ? (I don't think there's a word or phrase for this other than 'playing dice'. Or is it one roll of the dice? (the latter is to 'roll the dice' or 'throw the dice')

Answer (score 1):

The word *dicing* does have as a secondary meaning "playing at dice," as this example from Kris Yon, [*How to Start a Hobby in Collecting Dice*](https://books.google.com/books?id=S8LIBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT4&dq=dicing+dice&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TcY-VfSIGov6oQTZ0ICABA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=dicing%20dice&f=false) (2014) indicates:

> The Romans were passionate gamblers, especially at the peak of the Roman Empire,and **dicing** was common though forbidden except during the Saturnalia. Horace derided youths who wasted time on **dicing** instead of horse-chasing. ... Tacitus stated that the Germans were passionately fond of **dicing**, so much that they would stake their personal liberty when bankrupt. During the Middle Ages, **dicing** became a favorite pastime of knights, who formed **dicing** schools and guilds.

Nevertheless, the normal English way to describe casting dice during a game is not "dicing," but "throwing the dice" or "rolling the dice." I believe that the expression "shake, rattle, and roll," which was used as the title of a [hit song by Big Joe Turner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9wTQsAgktg) in 1954 refers to the process of casting dice, too.

If you want to delight a bunch of U.S. English speakers in the midst of a lively game of Yahtzee, I recommend that—instead of announcing "Dicing!" as you shake up the cup of dice—you say (in your best Swedish accent) "Rolling them bones!"

Comment: On an unrelated note, I believe that dicing is also an element of the game Fruit Ninjas.

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dicing defines dicing as "gambling or playing with dice."

Comment: @ab2: It's certainly a more polite way to describe the activity than calling it "playing craps."